# How to handle scrapy status 400

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-request

Hello I had developed a **scraper** that crawls https://crypto.jobs and **scrapes** its jobs. My crawler works perfect on first page of webpage but when I try to request its next page its returns status code 400.

> HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

```
import scrapy
import w3lib.html

class CryptojobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cryptojobs'
    allowed_domains = ['crypto.jobs']
    start_urls = ['https://crypto.jobs/']

    def parse(self, response):

        jobs=response.css('.table-jobs').xpath('//tbody/tr[@class="highlighted"]')
        for job in jobs:
         
            job_url=job.css('.job-url::attr(href)').get()
           
            url = response.urljoin(job_url)
            if url:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.single_parse)

        nextUrl=response.css('ul.pagination li:last-of-type a::attr(href)').get()
        if nextUrl:
            nextPageUrl=response.urljoin(nextUrl)
            headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'}
            yield scrapy.Request(url=nextPageUrl, callback=self.parse,
                                 headers=headers,
                                 method='GET')



    def single_parse(self,response):
        items=dict()
        print(response)
```

I had changed user agent in settings.py and also tried with passing user-agent in headers of request.
Further anyone have idea that how I can achieve that.

Comment: Did you try without any user-agent? I mean delete from settings.py and in nextUrl headers

Comment: yes i had tried user-agent in headers and also in settings.py. But nothing worked out yet.